# How to set Django HTTP response version in views.py, say HTTP/0.9, HTTP/1.0 or HTTP/1.1?

Tags: django, http, view

I want to specify HTTP response version to HTTP/0.9, HTTP/1.0 or HTTP/1.1 in views.py. How could I do that? Is there any variable like http_version that I can use?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the http protocol within a Django view.

You would have to make the change at the HTTP server level rather than at the application's view level.

For example, if you are using Apache, you would have to change the Apache configurations.

Comment: Hi Winnie, thanks for your answer! I'm using nginx as web server together with fastcgi. Do you know how to configure nginx.conf to set HTTP response version?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have do not have any experience with nginx.